# bash cat multiple files content in to single string without newlines

Tags: bash, file, cat

i got some files with name start as eg_. and only each contains one single line

eg_01.txt:
@china:129.00

eg_02.txt
@uk:219.98

eg_03.txt
@USA:341.90

......

i am expecting to cat them in to a single line to send by URL like:
@china:129.00@uk:219.98@USA:341.90

i use 
echo `cat eg_*`

it give me the output look like a string, but it actually contains new line:
"@china:129.00

@uk:219.98 
@USA:341.90"

is there any other way i can construct that string which expected and get rid of new line and even the space?  is only cat enough to do this?

thanks in advance

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739427/bash-add-string-to-the-end-of-the-file-without-line-break

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could always pipe it to `tr`

```
tr "\n" " "
```

That removes all newlines on `stdin` and replaces them with spaces

**EDIT**: as suggested by Bart Sas, you could also remove newlines with `tr -d`

```
tr -d "\n"
```

(note: just specifying an empty string to `tr` for the second argument won't do)

Comment: If you do not want spaces between the strings you can use tr -d '\n' instead.

Comment: Note for a very small number of people who will have files with Windows line terminators: "\r\n" will be the string used.

Answer (score 3):

Using only one command

```
url=$(awk '{printf "%s",$0}' eg*)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Perl, you'd do it like this:

```
perl -pe'chomp' eg*.txt
```

The `-p` says "loop through the input file and do whatever code is specified by the `-e` switch.  The `chomp` in Perl says "Remove any trailing newlines."