# Merging two files with cat without new line

Tags: linux, shell

I want to merge two files `cat file1 file2 > file3`. But it starts with new line. I don't want that. I could use tr to replace all new lines to space, but I can't do that, because there are new lines in files which I don't want to replace.

Comment: does it? my cat (on cygwin) doesn't put any extra new lines before or after any of 2 files. Are you sure you don't have the new line in file1 or file2?

Comment: Can you clarify what `file1` and `file2` look like, and just what output you want in `file3`?  Exactly what new lines do you want in the output, and what new lines don't you want?

Answer (score 23):

You could use `head` with `-1` as the `-c` flags parameter and `-q`

```
head -c -1 -q file1 file2 > file3
```

`head -c -1` will output everything up to the last 1 byte of the code (in this case the last 1 byte - endline - wont be included).  The `-q` is so the filenames dont get piped to `file3` as `head` does by default when `head`ing multiple files.

---

Or, as suggested by this answer - [*bash cat multiple files content in to single string without newlines*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936738/bash-cat-multiple-files-content-in-to-single-string-without-newlines)
, pipe it to `tr`:

```
tr -d "\n"
```

Answer (score 2):

in bash, you can do:

```
cat <(sed -n '1n;p' file1) <(sed -n '1n;p' file2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
user$ echo hi1 > file1       #for example
user$ echo hi2 > file2       #for example
user$ x=$(cat file1 file2)
user$ echo -n $x > file3
user$ cat file3
hi1 hi2                      #no newline is added.
```

Answer (score -1):

you ca use awk:

```
awk '(FNR>1){print}' file1 file2
```

**update - how it works:**

we ask `awk` to process two files: `file1` and `file2`. It will print whole record (line) if condition `(FNR>1)` if true. `FNR` is a variable [defined as](http://linux.die.net/man/1/awk):

*FNR - The input record number in the current input file.*

so, condition `(FNR>1)` will be true every time, except for the first line of each file. This way we skip first line of each file.