# Bash: add string to the end of the file without line break

Tags: linux, bash, awk, echo, cat

How can I add string to the end of the file without line break?

for example if i'm using >> it will add to the end of the file with line break:

```
cat list.txt
yourText1
root@host-37:/# echo yourText2 >> list.txt
root@host-37:/# cat list.txt
yourText1
yourText2
```

I would like to add yourText2 right after yourText1

```
root@host-37:/# cat list.txt
yourText1yourText2
```

Comment: echo -n seems to be the command you look for.

Comment: here may be [the answer you want](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/412835/append-text-with-echo-without-new-line); Note that if you also want to use a variable in sed comman,  variable in single quote would not get expended, use double quote instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sed '$s/$/yourText2/' list.txt > _list.txt_ && mv -- _list.txt_ list.txt
```

If your *sed* implementation supports the *-i* option, you could use:

```
sed -i.bck '$s/$/yourText2/' list.txt
```

With the second solution you'll have a backup too (with first you'll need to do it manually).

Alternatively:

```
ex -sc 's/$/yourText2/|w|q' list.txt
```

or

```
perl -i.bck -pe's/$/yourText2/ if eof' list.txt
```

Comment: Note: if your text file comes from Mac/Dos, this will not identify the EoL character. You'll need to run dos2unix on the file first.

Answer (score 75):

You can use the -n parameter of echo. Like this:

```
$ touch a.txt
$ echo -n "A" >> a.txt
$ echo -n "B" >> a.txt
$ echo -n "C" >> a.txt
$ cat a.txt
ABC
```

EDIT: Aha, you already had a file containing string and newline. Well, I'll leave this here anyway, might we useful for someone.

Comment: very proper, sir that is how I would carry it out. plus if you're not starting with a file then `>>` will touch it with any extenion you give or none at all, for example one my favorite lines of code:  `$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh itsme@nopasswordcheckneeded.com 'cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys'` then the next line is `$ ssh-add -K` and walla! no more password prompt every time I need to remote onto that machine

Answer (score 13):

Just use `printf` instead, since it does not print the new line as default:

```
printf "final line" >> file
```

#### Test

Let's create a file and then add an extra line without a trailing new line. Note I use `cat -vet` to see the new lines.

```
$ seq 2 > file
$ cat -vet file
1$
2$
$ printf "the end" >> file
$ cat -vet file
1$
2$
the end
```

Comment: For a very obscure reason `echo -n` didn't work when ran from Ansible shell. Your answer made my day.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers didn't work for me. Posting a Python implementation in case anyone finds it useful.

```
python -c "txtfile = '/my/file.txt' ; f = open(txtfile, 'r') ; d = f.read().strip() ; f.close() ; d = d + 'the data to append' ; open(txtfile, 'w').write(d)"
```